# XSLT: Pass element name as string and transform it to XPATH expression

Tags: xml, string, templates, xpath, xslt-3.0

Is it possible with XSLT 3.0 to **transform a string to an element name in a XPATH-query**? I would like to pass the name of an element as a string to a template and then include the name of the element in an XPATH-expression. Something like this `<xsl:variable name="el-name" select="'p'"/><xsl:copy-of select="$el-name"/>` where `el-name` is not a string anymore, but selects the element p.
Let's suppose I have a source document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<text xmlns="">
    <list xml:id="p-1">
        <item n="1"/>
        <item n="2"/>
    </list>
    <head>This is a heading</head>
    <p xml:id="p-1">Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p xml:id="p-2">dolorosum</p>
</text>
```

And a stylesheet like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xpath-default-namespace="" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" xmlns="">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/text">
        <selection-of-text xmlns="">
            <xsl:call-template name="get-elements">
                <xsl:with-param name="element-name" as="xs:string" select="'list'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:call-template name="get-elements">
                <xsl:with-param name="element-name" as="xs:string" select="'p'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </selection-of-text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="get-elements">
        <xsl:param name="element-name"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$element-name = 'list'">
                <xsl:copy-of select="list"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$element-name = 'p'">
                <xsl:copy-of select="p"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In BASH I run

```
java -cp "/mnt/c/Tools/SaxonHE9-9-1-4J/saxon9he.jar" net.sf.saxon.Transform \
-s:source.xml -xsl:stylesheet.xslt -o:output.xml
```

and get the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selection-of-text>
    <list xml:id="p-1">
        <item n="1"/>
        <item n="2"/>
    </list>
    <p xml:id="p-1">Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p xml:id="p-2">dolorosum</p>
</selection-of-text>
```

My code works but it is clumsy. I suppose `xsl:evaluate` might work to dynamically construct the proper XPATH expression but I don't get how. https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#evaluate-effect

Comment: The general XSLT 3 way to dynamic XPath evaluation is indeed `xsl:evaluate`, only as a optional feature that is not supported in the open source HE version of Saxon you seem to be using. On the other hand, the simple case of an element name can be easily solved since XSLT 1 by selecting `*[name() = $element-name]`, without any need for dynamic XPath evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin Honnen kindly explained above, a simple and short solution is this:

```
<xsl:template name="get-elements">
    <xsl:param name="element-name"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="*[name() = $element-name]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

An alternative solution, that I tested with Saxon PE 9.9.1.4, is this:

```
<xsl:template name="get-elements">
    <xsl:param name="element-name"/>
    <xsl:variable name = "els">
        <xsl:evaluate xpath="$element-name" context-item="."/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$els"/>
</xsl:template>
```